# Bitbake CMake recipe failing to find header files

Tags: c++, cmake, yocto, bitbake

I have a custom layer with two recipes `helper` and `dependent`. Recipe `helper` is a cmake based library from a public repository i.e. I do not plan on modifying any of the source fiels but I wrote the bb file for it which essentially consists of grabbing the source from git and the line `inherit pkgconfig cmake`. I did not do a `do_install` in `helper` because I was planning on statically linking `dependent`

Recipe `dependent` is a custom Cmake based C++ application that depends on `helper`. I have correctly added `helper` to the `DEPENDS` variable. When I go to compile, a header file in `dependent` has:

```cpp
#include <helper/foo.h>
```

The compiler correctly finds `foo.h` at `/long/context/usr/include/helper/foo.h`. However, `foo.h` has:

```cpp
#include <subdir/bar.h>
```

which is located at `/long/context/usr/include/helper/subdir/bar.h` and always results in `fatal error: subdir/bar.h: No such file or directory`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Compiler don't find `foo.h` but `helper/foo.h` i.e. it must have `/usr/include` as include folder
2. If you want to find `subdir/bar.h` you must have `/usr/include/helper` as include folder aka your compile line must contains `-i /usr/include/helper` or `-system /usr/include/helper` **OR** replace it by `#include <helper/subdir/bar.h>`
3. Unless you provide us the CMakeList.txt, recipe and pkg config we can't know which include directories are exported...

Comment: ```If you want to find subdir/bar.h you must have /usr/include/helper as include folder...```


That's what I'm asking how to do. Neither adding `/usr/include/helper` to `include_directories` nor `target_include_directories` in the CMakeLists resolves the issue. There is no "compile line". The line `inherit pkgconfig cmake` automatically takes care of configuration and compilation in the bitbake file.